# figure out which embedded FB video triggered the event

Tags: javascript, facebook, video, iframe, fbsdk

We are adding custom tracking to embedded Facebook videos. There could be multiple video embeds on a single page. In order to figure out what video sent the event, we look at `msg.instance.$VideoController1` property and match that with the iframes` name attribute. This gives us the iframe tag containing our video.

```
$("iframe[name='"+ msg.instance.$VideoController1 +"']").parent().parent().parent().parent().siblings("a").attr("href");
```

It works great [right now], but $VideoController1 and friends are not officially exposed. How can the player instance [-same as msg.instance] be easily matched to the iframe HTML element using the official developer API? Ideas...

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using msg.id helps. It can be added to the layer containing the iframe then matched in a similar fashion - `$("div[id='" + msg.id + "']").parent().parent().siblings("a").attr("href");`